# HTML/Javascript: How do you change input tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

Heres some of what I got, its a calculator, I'mg tryign to call the JS method from the button click events, something wrong though, display won't update.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js"> 
        var display = document.getElementById('display');

        function digit( num ){
            if(display == 0){
                display.innerHTML = num;
                } else {
                    display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML + "" + num;
                    }
        };


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="calculator">
      <table width="auto" border="1">
        <tr>
          <!--<td colspan=4><input id="display" type="text"></td> -->
          <td colspan=4><div id="display"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>MC</td>
          <td>MR</td>
          <td>MS</td>
          <td><input type="button" value='/' onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="button" value=7 onclick="javascript:digit(this.value);"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value=8 onclick="javascript.digit(this.value);"></td>
          <td><input  type="button" value=9 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
          <td><input  type="button" value='*' onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input  type="button" value=4 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
          <td><input  type="button" value=5 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
          <td><input  type="button" value=6 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
```

Comment: What's the `pushButton` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move

```
var display = document.getElementById('display');
```

into your function.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `document.getElementById('display');` before that element (`id=display`) exists.  You can do a variety of things, but the easiest would just be to move the `<script>` to just before `</body>`, or at least after `id=display`

Answer (score 0):

Place 0 in the div  Or change the condition in script  (display == null )